CORS preflight check Error with iframe in react and ASP.Net iframe Service
I have a Next.js application running locally on http://localhost:3000/ and a Java backend on http://localhost:8080/. I also have a text Editor service running on https://localhost:44349, and this text Editor service is embeded in my Nextjs application using iFrame.
When an Axios request is sent from the frontend, the request headers are getting set automatically to Access-Control-Allow-Origin to iFrame source instead of backend source, and this is resulting in a CORS error.
If I remove the iFrame, everything works fine, but how can I resolve the error with the iFrame please?
The Error:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/Alerts' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://localhost:44349' that is not equal to the supplied origin.


how do i resolve these error - start by responding with the correct value in access-control-allow-origin

when i make a request to java server http://localhost:8080/Alerts it automatically sets the  access-control-allow-origin to https://localhost:44349 and the error has that is not equal to the supplied origin then from where do i send the correct access-control-allow-origin (java or ASP.net)

what is it and why does it do that?

i dont know why it is doing this but
When i add iframe service of ASP.Net e.g

then all other requests to localhost:8080 it automatically getting the access-control-allow-origin to localhost:44349 instead of  localhost:8080 if i remove iframe then the access-control-allow-origin is localhost:8080 and  everything works fine
i dont know why it is doing this - something in your code perhaps?
